# Setting content type using BlobServiceClient

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` [library v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=environment-variable-windows) to upload files to my Azure Blob Storage container.

It's working fine but I haven't been able to figure out a way to set the `content-type` for the file.

I found some documentation but the intellisense is not giving me any options to set `BlobHttpHeaders`. How do I set the content type for the file I upload?

Here's my code

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
    private string containerName = "my-container";
    private static string connectionString = "my-connection-string";
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _client;

    public StorageService()
    {
        _client = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadFile(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Generate a unique name for the blob we're uploading
            var blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "__" + fileName;

            var _blobContainerClient = _client.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                await _blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return blobName;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by content-type?

Comment: mime type e.g. `image/jpeg`, etc.

Comment: Add it to the name of the stream your saving. for example fileName.jpeg

Comment: It's there already but that's not doing the trick though. When I check the uploaded file on Azure Blob Storage, it's showing `application/octet-stream` as its content type even though it's a `jpg` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
try
{
// Generate a unique name for the blob we're uploading
var blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "__" + fileName;
var _blobContainerClient = _client.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

BlobClient blob = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders();
string extension = Path.GetExtension(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
switch (extension.ToLower())
{
    case ".jpg":
    case ".jpeg":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        break;
    case ".png":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/png";
        break;
    case ".gif":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/gif";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

await using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    var uploadedBlob = await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream, blobHttpHeader);
}
}
catch
{
  throw new Exception();
}
```

please check this too :
[check](https://cerebrata.com/blog/how-to-set-the-content-type-of-blobs-based-on-its-file-extension-in-bulk)

Comment: I see that you've switched from `BlobServiceClient` to `BlobClient`.  In all honesty, I don't know the difference between the two. As you can see in my code, I was instantiating `BlobServiceClient` in the constructor so that I can reuse it in all my methods e.g. `UploadFile()` and other methods. The `BlobClient` wants `filename` when you instantiate it so how would I reuse it if I instantiate it inside the `UploadFile()` method because filename will be different everytime I use the `BlobClient`?

Comment: Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet#methods), it is not possible to set the content type when using `UploadBlobAsync` method in `BlobContainerClient`. You will need to use `BlobClient`.

Comment: Hey @GauravMantri. Thanks for chiming in. Does that mean I’m creating a new instance of BlobClient every time I upload a file?

Comment: That’s correct and it’s completely fine.